# \W RegEx JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

What is this RegEx `/[\W_]/g` in JavaScript?  I know the `\W` locates non-word characters, but what does the `_` do?

Comment: It means `_` since it is in a char set.

Comment: Uhh, the `_` is the `_` character (which is a word character).

Comment: http://regexper.com/#%2F%5B%5CW_%5D%2Fg

Comment: It's a character set. `\W` is equivalent to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`, (i.e., not (`a-zA-Z0-9_`) , and `_` will match `_`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole regex string will match anything that is not letters and numbers

It is the same as [^a-zA-Z0-9]

The \W is included: (as you said) matches non word characters

the _ is included so it matches the literal underscore character that wouldn't be accepted in \W